# Placing query Map<String, sObject> values into separate variables or array of variables and printing fields with null values

Tags: arrays, apex, soql

I am currently querying the OrderItem sObject and I'm trying to separate the values in the query into separate variables. I perform the query and have run into two problems.

1. I've tried performing a get and placing the values into variables but end up with a null value even though system debug shows values for the specific fields. There might be some instances where there would be more than 1 OrderItemNumber returned along with the other values if there are more than one line item.
2. I cant seem to pass the values from the list in my code below to another list.
3. Some of the values in the list do not print when performing a system debug. For example if ListPrice is empty it wont print out the name of the field with a null following after it nor will it print out the field name at all.

Please reference my code below.

`Map<String, OrderItem> order_items = new Map<String, OrderItem>([
                SELECT OrderItemNumber, ListPrice, UnitPrice, 
                TotalPrice
                FROM OrderItem 
                WHERE Order.OrderNumber = :order_number // holds the order number of
                                                        // the Order sObject that
                                                        // the query is being 
                                                        // performed for
            ]);`

Answer (score 0):

1 - This is probably happening because the key in your Map is going to be the `OrderItem` record Id and not the `OrderItemNumber` as I suspect what you're really after. If you're wanting to look up `OrderItem` records from the map via the `OrderItemNumber`, you will need to change that to:

```
Map<String, OrderItem> order_items = new Map<String, OrderItem>();

for(OrderItem oi : [SELECT OrderItemNumber, ListPrice, UnitPrice, TotalPrice FROM OrderItem WHERE Order.OrderNumber = :order_number]) {
    order_items.put(oi.OrderItemNumber, oi);
}

//Now you can get a specific OrderItem:
OrderItem o = order_items.get(<your-order-item-number>);
```

2 - You can get the list of OrderItems by calling `order_items.values()` on that map.

3 - This is just default Salesforce behavior when trying to debug things, it doesn't put `null` in the debug logs, it just doesn't print the property at all :/